# How to calculate the number of partial derangements of a multiset in Mathematica?

Tags: combinatorics

I have found some helpful information on enumerating derangements at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4645664/the-number-of-partial-derangements-of-a-52-card-deck-ignoring-suits, [https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/multider.pdf](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/multider.pdf), and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147657/derangements-of-multisets.

I have designed a function to enumerate derangements of a multiset:

```wl
EnumerateMultisetDerangments // ClearAll
EnumerateMultisetDerangements[multiset_] :=
 (*Length[ResourceFunction["MultisetDerangements"][multiset]]*)
 Module[
  {numberOfRepeatedElementsAssociation, numberOfRepeatedElementsValues}, 
  numberOfRepeatedElementsAssociation = Counts[multiset];
  numberOfRepeatedElementsValues = Values[numberOfRepeatedElementsAssociation]; 
  Abs@
    Integrate[
      Product[LaguerreL[n, x], {n, numberOfRepeatedElementsValues}] Exp[-x], 
      {x, 0, Infinity}
    ]
  ]
```

I am interested in generalizing this program to the case of partial derangements. In other words, I'd like to construct a similar function to the one above: let's call it for example `EnumerateMultisetPartialDerangements`. How can I do this?

I've tried to understand the Python program given in an answer to [The number of partial derangements of a 52-card deck (ignoring suits)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4645664/the-number-of-partial-derangements-of-a-52-card-deck-ignoring-suits), but I couldn't figure it out.

This function *lists* all multiset partial derangements:

```wl
PartialDerangements // ClearAll
PartialDerangements[set_, 
  number_?(IntegerQ[#] && # \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers &)] := 
 Select[Count[SameQ @@@ Transpose[{#, set}], False] === number &][
  Permutations[set]]

MultisetPartialDerangements // ClearAll
MultisetPartialDerangements[set_, number_, 
  Optional[limit_, 
   All]] :=(*Module[{length,assoc,derangements,list1},length=Length[\
set];assoc=AssociationThread[Array[Identity[#]&,length]->set];\
derangements=PartialDerangements[set,number];list1=Table[Lookup[assoc,\
derangment],{derangment,derangements}];Take[Select[Count[MapThread[\
Equal,{set,#}],True]==number&][Permutations[set]],limit]]*)
 Take[Select[Count[MapThread[Equal, {set, #}], True] == number &][
   Permutations[set]], limit]
```

I'd like my desired `EnumerateMultisetPartialDerangements` to return the value of `Length@ EnumerateMultisetPartialDerangements[set]`, but without actually generating all the partial derangements. How can I do this?

I think the solution hinges on the integral of a product of Laguerre polynomials times $\exp(-x)$ from 0 to $\infty$.

I would also like a solution that is fast enough to reproduce the answer for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4645664/the-number-of-partial-derangements-of-a-52-card-deck-ignoring-suits in a reasonable amount of time for a standard deck of 52 cards with 0 to 52 fixed points. I have only been able to calculate this for 0 to 6 fixed points. This took 334.672 s.
[image]

It seems the person who calculated this for all values from 0 to 52 fixed points must have used a faster method. I think the thing that's slowing down the calculation is Subsets.

Comment: I might be the only one but I'm not at all clear as to what you're asking.  You ask about generalizing the first set of code to `EnumerateMultisetPartialDerangements`.  Then you show code for a function that "lists all multiset partial derangements".  But the code doesn't give any specific example.  Are you asking help to debug code or write code?  Clearly I'm not understanding.

Comment: I don't want to list all the multiset partial derangements then, call Length to find the number of derangements of multisets. I want to calculate the number with a formula, like how you can use Binomial, instead of calling Length on Subsets.

Comment: For more details, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731810/what-is-a-formula-for-enumerate-multiset-partial-derangements?noredirect=1#comment10030453_4731810.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1.

```
ClearAll[countPartialDerangements]

countPartialDerangements[lst_, nfixed_] := Count[Permutations[lst], 
  p_ /; Inner[SameQ, p, lst, BooleanCountingFunction[{nfixed}, Length@lst]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
lst = {green, blue, blue, green, green, green, red, blue, red};
 
Grid[{Prepend["fixed"] @ #, 
 Prepend["count"] @ Map[countPartialDerangements[lst, #] &] @ #} & @ Range[0, 9],
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

#### 2.

Using the function `DerangementsCount` from the docs [LaguerreL > Applications](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaguerreL.html):

```
ClearAll[DerangementsCount, vCounts, partialDerangementsCount]

DerangementsCount[nvec_List] := Integrate[
  Exp[-x] Times @@ ((-1)^nvec LaguerreL[nvec, x]), {x, 0, ∞}]

vCounts[lst_, nfixed_] := Counts @ Map[Sort @* Values @* Counts] @ 
   Subsets[lst, {Length @ lst - nfixed}]

partialDerangementsCount[lst_, nfixed_] := Total @ 
 KeyValueMap[#2 DerangementsCount @ # &] @ vCounts[lst, nfixed]
```

***Examples:***

```
lst = {green, blue, blue, green, green, green, red, blue, red};

Grid[{Prepend["fixed"] @ #, 
 Prepend["count"] @ Map[partialDerangementsCount[lst, #] &] @ #} & @ Range[0, 9],
Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: You could take the absolute value instead of multiplying by -1 to a power because you know the result will be nonnegative.

Comment: Good point @PeterBurbery. (Copied that piece from the docs.)

Comment: I tried to make this work with a set with 52 elements for a deck of cards but it slowed down because of Subsets. Is there a way to speed this up without the slowdown from Subsets? Thank you for providing a solution to the problem.

Comment: @PeterBurbery, 
can' t think of a way to make either method faster to handle 52 - 
 deck . Perhaps someone can translate to mma  the code in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4646095/18912) in the link you provided.